# Can someone help me shorten this giant code?

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, performance, arraylist

Can this giant code be shortened ?:
So basically this code get rid of the language ISO" codes
Like if I wanted to translate **مرحبا يا صديقي بك في بيتي!** from Arabic to English
It would come out like this **Welcome my friend to my home!**
But if I were to translate **مرحبا يا صديقي بك في بيتي!** with my old translate command it would come out looking like this **en Welcome my friend to my home!** with **en**.

Here is my code:

`

```
const { Client, Message, MessageEmbed } = require("discord.js")
const translate = require('@iamtraction/google-translate')
module.exports = {
  name: "ترجم",
  description: `يترجم اللغه فقط أستعمل !translate "الكلمه/الجمله يلي بدك تترجمها"`,
  aliases: ["translate"],
  run: async (client, message, args) => {
    try {
      const query = args.join(" ")
      const lang = args[0]
      if (!query) throw new Error('Please specify a text to translate');
      const translated = await translate(query, { to: lang });
      fulltranslated = translated.text
      console.log("fulltranslate: " + fulltranslated)
      if (fulltranslated.startsWith("ar") || fulltranslated.startsWith("en") || fulltranslated.startsWith("yi") || fulltranslated.startsWith("cy") || fulltranslated.startsWith("vi") || fulltranslated.startsWith("ur") || fulltranslated.startsWith("uk") || fulltranslated.startsWith("tr") || fulltranslated.startsWith("th") || fulltranslated.startsWith("sv") || fulltranslated.startsWith("sw") || fulltranslated.startsWith("es") || fulltranslated.startsWith("sl") || fulltranslated.startsWith("sk") || fulltranslated.startsWith("sr") || fulltranslated.startsWith("ru") || fulltranslated.startsWith("ro") || fulltranslated.startsWith("pt") || fulltranslated.startsWith("pt") || fulltranslated.startsWith("pl") || fulltranslated.startsWith("pl") || fulltranslated.startsWith("fa") || fulltranslated.startsWith("no") || fulltranslated.startsWith("mt") || fulltranslated.startsWith("ms") || fulltranslated.startsWith("mk") || fulltranslated.startsWith("lt") || fulltranslated.startsWith("lv") || fulltranslated.startsWith("de")) {
        without2 = fulltranslated.substring(3);
        console.log("بدون: " + without2)
        Embed1 = new MessageEmbed()
          .setColor('RANDOM')
          .setTitle('Translate | ترجمة')
          .setDescription(without2)
        message.reply({ embeds: [Embed1] });
      } else if(fulltranslated.startsWith("zh-CN") || fulltranslated.startsWith("zh-TW")) {
        without2 = fulltranslated.substring(6);
        Embed1 = new MessageEmbed()
          .setColor('RANDOM')
          .setTitle('Translate | ترجمة')
          .setDescription(without2)
        message.reply({ embeds: [Embed1] })
      } else {
        without2 = fulltranslated.replace("ar", "")
        Embed1 = new MessageEmbed()
        .setColor('RANDOM')
        .setTitle('Translate | ترجمة')
        .setDescription(without2)
        message.reply({ embeds: [Embed1] })
      }
    } catch (err) {
      if (message) {
        message.reply('Translation failed: ' + err.message);
      }
    }
  },
};
```

`

I tried to shortened the code
I tried to make an array...

Answer (score 0):

You can use a regex to match the language code and replace it with an empty string.

```js
const without2 = fulltranslated.replace(/^[a-z]{2}(-[A-Z]{2})?/, '');
```

Regex explanation:
`^` - start of string
`[a-z]{2}` - 2 lowercase letters
`(-[A-Z]{2})?` - optional group of a dash followed by 2 uppercase letters